# Cast lambda expression to Func<IObserver<char>, IDisposable>

Tags: c#, casting, lambda, idisposable

I read the following example in Programming C# 5.0. Why it is possible to convert this lambda expression to `Func<IObserver<char>, IDisposable>` when it does not return an IDisposable.

```
IObservable<char> singularHotSource = Observable.Create(
    (Func<IObserver<char>, IDisposable>)(obs =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            obs.OnNext(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: I'd say it's because the loop is infinite, so the return value won't be reached anyway. If you make the loop non-infinite, you'll get a compile-time error. But *why* is it implemented like that? That's more of a question for Eric Lippert...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Patryk notes, this is *basically* the same as asking: "why is this allowed to say that it returns `int`, when it doesn't?":

```
    int SomeMethod()
    {
        while (true) { }
    }
```

And by answer; it doesn't, in any code path, return something *different* (another type, or `void`) - so sure, why not; the compiler can represent that as a method that returns `int`.